# Ошибка при выполнении кода x+=2: TypeError: must be str, not int

Tags: python, python-3.x

В условии задания получить значение х, записать его в файл, в диапазоне от -10 до 0 с шагом 2, вычислить квадраты х и записать в другой файл. Во время выполнения вылетают ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

```
def func():
    while True:
        print('х:')
        x = input()
        if x == '-10':
            break
    f = open ("file1.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(x))
    f.close()
    f = open("file1.txt", "r")
    f2 = open ("file2.txt", "w")
    while True:
        x += 2
        if x == '0':
            break
        y = x**2
        f2.write(str(y))

    return print('+')

func()
```

Ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 24, in <module>
    func()
  line 16, in func
    x += 2
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: Укажите ошибки в вопросе.

Comment: Для чего нужен первый цикл `while`?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

у вас переменная `x` является типом `str` переведите его в `int` исправленный код
P.s немного подредактировал

```
def func():
    x = int(input('х:'))
    if x == -10:
        with open("file1.txt", "w") as file_1, open("file2.txt", "w") as file_2:
            file_1.write(str(x))
            while x != 0:
                x += 2
                y = x**2
                file_2.write(str(y) + '\n')
            return print('+')
    else:
        return func()


func()
```

Answer (score 0):

вы выполняете ввод в строковом виде, а для того, чтобы 16 строчка работала, вам просто его нужно переделать в числовой вид, добавив перед ним int()